# How to print to PDF while appending to an existing document?

Tags: pdf, printing, software-rec, libreoffice

I am considering installing Linux Mint.

I need to be able to Print to PDF, which appears to be as simple as selecting Print to PDF as the printer, however I also need to be able to append to existing documents. I have yet to confirm this can be done in Linux. In Windows, there are certain PDF editors that allow this to be done: Gaaiho PDF Suite, Abode Acrobat & Nova PDF can do this.

In Windows, I use the Gaaiho PDF Suite to do this task. I simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, click on the existing PDF, and it adds the new page to the PDF. Unfortunately, Gaaiho does not support Linux.

So, are there any higher end PDF Suites for Linux that provide more advanced Print to PDF options? This may be the deal breaker for me in converting to Linux again.

Google searching has not yielded any conclusive results apart from commands that will merge separate PDFs into one. This will not be efficient enough for me. I must be able to append to existing documents as I go along.

There must be a way.

Comment: You can try to write your own printer driver, using existing tools to merge PDF files. There's no pre-made driver for this. If you *must* have one and can't get your own hands dirty, than that's a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems there is no direct way of appending the pdf files generated by default when using the print to pdf option.

But you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf) for command line tools you can use to merge the generated file into one.